# How to convert an ArrayList<Integer> to ArrayList<String>?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, type-conversion, integer

I have to convert an Int arraylist to String Arraylist so JText in swing can print the numbers of the String ArrayList.

```
private static ArrayList<Integer> numen = new ArrayList<Integer>
((Collections.nCopies(49,0)));

private static ArrayList<String> numens = new ArrayList<String>
((Collections.nCopies(49, "0")));
for (int  myInt : numen){ numens.add(String.valueOf(myInt)); }
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Integer.toString would seem to be better idea - but there’s going to be some fancy pancy way to use streams/map 

Comment: @MadProgrammer Why is `Integer.toString()` better than `String.valueOf()`?

Comment: Why not - it would seem a more appropriate concept - I want to convert a  “integer” to a “string”, to me, it just reads better 

Comment: @shmosel `String#valueOf(int)` just uses `Integer.toString` anyway, so you could save yourself a whole method call , and make it more readable 

Comment: That's very much a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
    
List<String> stringVals = numbers.stream().map(a -> a.toString()).collect(Collectors.toList());
stringVals.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

## `toString`

If your goal is a textual representation of the integers, just call [`AbstractCollection#toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString()) on your original `ArrayList< Integer >`. No need to create another list.

```
List< Integer > integers = List.of( 1 , 2 , 3 ) ;
String output = integers.toString() ;
```

See this [code run live at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/LLYhk8).

> [1, 2, 3]

## `Stream#map`

If your goal is generating text, use a stream to generate text with newlines. Calling `Stream#map` changes our stream of `Integer` objects into a stream of `String` objects. We combine those with a `StringBuilder`, producing a final multi-line `String` object at the end.

```java
List < Integer > integers = List.of( 1 , 2 , 3 );
String s =
        integers
                .stream()
                .map( integer -> integer.toString() + "\n" )
                .collect( StringBuilder :: new , StringBuilder :: append , StringBuilder :: append )
                .toString();
```

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3

Answer (score 0):

The code you are using for the conversion is fine:

```
ArrayList<String> numens = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int  myInt : numen) { 
    numens.add(String.valueOf(myInt)); 
}
```

As explained, in @Ryan's answer, you could also do this using Java 8+ streams.  But (IMO) that is not a significant improvement.

Note: if you are looking for a way to do this without creating a new list, that is not possible in Java.

---

But the thing that puzzles me is your rationalization for doing this:

> I have to convert an `Integer` `Arraylist` to `String` `Arraylist` so `JText` in Swing can print the numbers of the `String` `ArrayList`.

Firstly, there is no `JText` type.  There is a `JTextField` or a `JTextArea`.

Secondly, neither of these class accept a `List` to populate the field or area.

So ...

If you are just populating a single field / area from a list, you are going to have to convert the list to a string.  And if you are doing that, you don't need to convert an `ArrayList<Integer>` to an `ArrayList<String>` to do it.   For example, just call `toString()` on the `ArrayList<Integer>` will format it so that it can be inserted into a `JTextField` or `JTextArea`.

If you are just populating a list or array of fields / areas from the list, you are going to have to iterate the list to do it.  At that point, you may as well iterate the original `ArrayList<Integer>`.

In short, your question appears to be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).